# Get count of string in vim

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, substitute

To get the count of a string I usually do something a bit hack-ish such as the following:

1. Do a `:%s`ubstitution on the string in question, such as:

   ```
   # how many times does the string "<Item " occur in the file?
   :%s/\<Item //g
   ```
2. Read the output:

   ```
   2009 substitutions on 2009 lines
   ```
3. Do an undo to go back to the original state of things.

   <kbd>u</kbd>

---

Is there a more straightforward way to get the count of occurrences of a string in vim?

Comment: Would the function `searchcount()` work for you?

Comment: @Mass sure, I've never heard of that before. Want to post a brief answer showing an example and a link to docs for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiomatic answer is

```
:%substitute/pat//gn
```

Mass mentions `searchcount()` which returns a dictionary of interesting items. You'll need to set the last search pattern, though (e.g., `/` or write to `@/`), or pass `pattern` in the options to the function.